# Typescript Error Cannot find type definition file for 'cordova-plugin-ionic'

Tags: ionic-framework, console

when i am doing ionic serve i get the following error :

```js
[app-scripts] [21:34:58]  typescript: ...nt app/ecommerce-app/node_modules/@ioni
c/pro/dist/src/services/deploy/index.d.ts, line: 33
[app-scripts] [21:34:58]  typescript: ...nt app/ecommerce-app/node_modules/@ioni
c/pro/dist/src/services/deploy/index.d.ts, line: 99
[app-scripts] [21:34:58]  typescript: ...nt app/ecommerce-app/node_modules/@ioni
c/pro/dist/src/services/deploy/index.d.ts, line: 116
[app-scripts] [21:34:58]  typescript: ...nt app/ecommerce-app/node_modules/@ioni
c/pro/dist/src/services/deploy/index.d.ts, line: 120
[app-scripts] [21:34:58]  typescript: ...nt app/ecommerce-app/node_modules/@ioni
c/pro/dist/src/services/deploy/index.d.ts, line: 132
[app-scripts] [21:34:58]  typescript: ...nt app/ecommerce-app/node_modules/@ioni
c/pro/dist/src/services/deploy/index.d.ts, line: 138
[app-scripts] [21:34:58]  typescript: ...nt app/ecommerce-app/node_modules/@ioni
c/pro/dist/src/services/deploy/index.d.ts, line: 142
[app-scripts] [21:34:58]  typescript: ...nt app/ecommerce-app/node_modules/@ioni
c/pro/dist/src/services/deploy/index.d.ts, line: 146
[app-scripts] [21:34:58]  typescript: ...nt app/ecommerce-app/node_modules/@ioni
c/pro/dist/src/services/deploy/index.d.ts, line: 156
[app-scripts] [21:34:58]  typescript: ...nt app/ecommerce-app/node_modules/@ioni
c/pro/dist/src/services/deploy/index.d.ts, line: 156
```

I have searched but no solution yet.

Comment: Please include your code and what you're trying to achieve. It is not clear to us what is going on here.

Comment: hi thanks for the comment, it is a restaurant app that i am trying locally, which part of the code do you want ?

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)